# Get activity process diagram by WSO2 bpmn 360 REST API

Tags: wso2

I want to get activity process diagram by WSO2 bpmn 360 REST API

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use : GET runtime/process-instances/{processInstanceId}/diagram

Refer [1] for detailed information about this REST API resource

[1] https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_get_diagram_for_a_process_instance

Comment: Thank you :). Its helpful for me